# How to display individual login message to linux users via /etc/motd

Tags: linux

`/etc/motd` displays common message to all users. Is it possible to display individual /etc/motd file for each users?

For example : 
User-1 logs in and see "message-1", but User-2 logs in and gets a "different message-2"

Comment: okay,this thread closed. check  'Related' topic there are lot of similar question answered. Are you guys going to close that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to control `motd` display based on user ids.

However, it is possible to configure the system so as to enable users to decide whether they want to see motd or not.  It can be achieved by adding a line to `/etc/login.defs`:

```
HUSHLOGIN_FILE   .hushlogin
```

Users doing `touch ${HOME}/.hushlogin` wouldn't see the motd.

Comment: Thanks , there is no way to control motd user basis.